# Escape $ in regex replacement string

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to turn the string `dkfj-dkfj-sflj` into `dkfj-woop$dkfj-sflj`.

Here's what I've tried:

```
var my_string = "dkfj-dkfj-sflj";
var regex = new RegExp("(\\w+)-(\\w+)-(\\w+)", "g");
console.log(my_string.replace(regex, "$1$woop[\$$2]$3");
```

And my result is: `dkfj-woop$2-sflj`. Because the "$" is in front of the "$2" capture group, it messes up that capture group.

Assuming I want the structure of my regex and capture group string to stay the same, what's the right way to escape that "$" so it works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That isn't how you escape a `$` for `replace`. Backslash escaping works at the parser level, functions like `replace` cannot give special meaning to new escape sequences like `\$` because they don't even *see* the `\$`. The string `"\$"` is exactly equivalent to the string `"$"`, both produce the same string. If you wanted to pass a backslash and a dollar sign to a function, it's the backslash itself that requires escaping: `"\\$"`.

Regardless, `replace` expects you to escape a `$` with `$$`. You need `"$1$woop[$$$2]$3"`; a `$$` for the literal `$`, and `$2` for he capture group.

Read [Specifying a string as a parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter) in the `replace` docs.

Answer (score 1):

Use `$$` in the replacement part to print a literal `$` symbol and you don't need to have a character class in the replacement part if your pattern was enclosed within forward slashes.

```
> var my_string = "dkfj-dkfj-sflj";
undefined
> my_string.replace(/(\w+)-\w+-(\w+)/, "$1-woop$$$1-$2")
'dkfj-woop$dkfj-sflj'
```